# *ngIf display then undisplay

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I write this after asking that: [Observable need a click to load on html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116566/observable-need-a-click-to-load-on-html-page)

The solution was good but the problem now is that I have every same id display because precedently I did :

```
getFeederArray(): Observable<Array<string>> {
    let toReturn: Array<string> = [];
    var subject = new Subject<Array<string>>();
    this.getUser().subscribe(user => {
      this.orders = this.db.collection("orders", ref => {
        return ref
        .where("clientId", "==", user.id)
      }).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<Order[]>;
      this.orders.subscribe(orders => {
        orders.forEach(order => {
          if(toReturn.indexOf(order.feederId) == -1) {  <---- to not have twice the same order
            toReturn.push(order.feederId);
          }
        })
      })
      subject.next(toReturn);
    })
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
```

And now I have :

```
getFeederArray(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.getUser().pipe(
      switchMap((user) => {
        this.orders = this.db
          .collection("orders", (ref) => ref.where("clientId", "==", user.id))
          .valueChanges({ idField: "id" }) as Observable<Order[]>;

        return this.orders;
      }),
      map((orders) => orders.map((order) => order.feederId))
    );
  }
```

Which no need a click no more, so the display is normal, but we can have twice the same order.
So I tried in my html :

```
<section class="mobile" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="20px" *ngFor="let id of _feedersId | async">
          <div *ngIf="this.isAlreadyDisplayed(id)">
            {{ cl(id) }}
            <app-feeder-card
            [feederId] = "id"
            [clientId] = "this.uid"
            ></app-feeder-card>
          </div>
</section>
```

With those functions in the .ts:

```
// push in array
  pushAlreadyDisplayed(str: string) {
    this.alreadyDisplayed.push(str);
  }

  // boolean already displayed
  isAlreadyDisplayed(str: string): boolean {
    const bool = this.alreadyDisplayed.includes(str);
    if(bool) {
      return !bool;
    } else {
      this.pushAlreadyDisplayed(str);
      return !bool;
    }
  }

  cl(str: string) {
    console.log(str);
  }
```

But a problem occurs : my page well `console.log` the ids (and that's good, there is no twice the same), but this part in the HTML :

```
{{ cl(id) }}
<app-feeder-card
   [feederId] = "id"
   [clientId] = "this.uid"
></app-feeder-card>
```

is only showed for less than 1 second and than disapear...
I don't understand why, and so I don't know how to solve my problem...

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you use pushAlreadyDisplayed() you make changes to alreadyDisplayed.
This thing cus to re-render the component, and on the 2nd iteration the ID is
marked as arealy renderd aleady.

A better solution is to reduce the array from the duplicates

Comment: Hello thank you, I want to do so, but I don't know if we can do that with the actual `getFeederArray()`, because firebase doesn't seem to do that. I don't have any idea... but I don't understand why actually the HTML page makes disappear this small part after 0,5s ?