# Array<Array<string>> need a click to load on html page

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I precedently post this topic: [Observable need a click to load on html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116566/observable-need-a-click-to-load-on-html-page), I have the same display problem: I have to click on the input to display the content of an `Array<Array<string>>`
`search.component.html`

```
<section>
    <div class="divPosition">
      <mat-icon>place</mat-icon>
      <mat-form-field color="accent" appearance="fill" id="searchAddress">
        <mat-label>*****</mat-label>
        <input 
          matInput 
          ngx-google-places-autocomplete #placesRef="ngx-places" 
          (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)" [ngModel]="this.address" />
        <button mat-button *ngIf="address" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="address=''">
          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <section class="mobile" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="20px" *ngFor="let docs of matchingDocs">
        <app-feeder-card
          [feederId] = "docs[0]"
          [clientId] = "docs[1]"
        ></app-feeder-card>
      </section>
      <section *ngIf="matchingDocs.length == 0" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayout="column">
        <app-no-feeder
          [lat] = this.lat
          [lng] = this.long
          [address] = this.address
        ></app-no-feeder>
      </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

`search.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { FeederService } from '../feeder/feeder.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-feeder',
  templateUrl: './search-feeder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-feeder.component.scss']
})
export class SearchFeederComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: number;
  long: number;
  address: string;
  matchingDocs: Array<Array<string>> = [];
  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private db: AngularFirestore, private feederService: FeederService, private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initialisePage();
    this.changeDetection.detectChanges();         // <---- don't work here
  }
  
  findArround(lat: number, long: number, ray: number) {
    const geofire = require('geofire-common');
    // Find feeder within [ray] km of London
    const center = [lat, long];
    const radiusInM = ray * 20;

    // Each item in 'bounds' represents a startAt/endAt pair. We have to issue
    // a separate query for each pair. There can be up to 9 pairs of bounds
    // depending on overlap, but in most cases there are 4.
    const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
    const promises = [];
    for (const b of bounds) {
      const q = this.db.collection('feeder'/*, ref => {
        return ref
          .orderBy("address")
          .startAt(b[0])
          .endAt(b[1])
      }*/)
      promises.push(q.get());
    }

    // Collect all the query results together into a single list
    Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
      var matchingDocs: Array<Array<string>> = [];
      var alreadyMatched: Array<string> = [];

      for (const snap of snapshots) {
        snap.subscribe(res => {
          res.forEach(data => {
            var point = this.feederService.getLatLng(data.id);
            point.subscribe(r => {
              const lat = r[0];
              const lng = r[1]
  
              // We have to filter out a few false positives due to GeoHash
              // accuracy, but most will match
              const distanceInKm = geofire.distanceBetween([lat, lng], center);
              const distanceInM = distanceInKm * 1000;
              if (distanceInM <= radiusInM) {
                if(!alreadyMatched.includes(data.id)) {
                  this.authService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
                    var uid = 'noUid'
                    if(this.authService.isAuth()) {
                      uid = user.uid;
                    }
                    this.feederService.getFeederById(data.id).subscribe(feeder => {
                      if(feeder.state) {
                        matchingDocs.push([data.id, uid]);
                      }
                    })
                  });
                  alreadyMatched.push(data.id);
                }
              }
            })
          })
        })
      }
      
      return matchingDocs;
    }).then((matchingDocs) => {
      // Process the matching documents
      this.matchingDocs = matchingDocs;
    });
  }

  public handleAddressChange(address: any) {
    this.address = address.formatted_address;
    const lat = address.geometry.location.lat();
    const lng = address.geometry.location.lng();
    const adrs = address.formatted_address;

    this.router.navigate(['/search-feeder/', lat, lng, adrs]);
    this.initialisePage(lat, lng, adrs);
  }

  initialisePage(lat?: number, lng?: number, address?: string) {
    if(lat) {
      this.lat = lat;
      this.long = lng;
      this.address = address;
    } else {
      this.lat = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lat'));
      this.long = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('long'));
      this.address = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('address');
    }

    this.findArround(this.lat, this.long, 200);
  }
}
```

The problematic part is this one :

```
<section class="mobile" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="20px" *ngFor="let docs of matchingDocs">
        <app-feeder-card
          [feederId] = "docs[0]"
          [clientId] = "docs[1]"
        ></app-feeder-card>
      </section>
```

I have to tell you that I'm using firestore as you see and more than that, this page is made for a localization search as you can see with `findArround(lat: number, long: number, ray: number)` method.
[EDIT]
To know, when I `console.log()` here :

```
  findArround(lat: number, long: number, ray: number) {
    const geofire = require('geofire-common');
    // Find feeder within [ray] km of London
    const center = [lat, long];
    const radiusInM = ray * 20;

    // Each item in 'bounds' represents a startAt/endAt pair. We have to issue
    // a separate query for each pair. There can be up to 9 pairs of bounds
    // depending on overlap, but in most cases there are 4.
    const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
    const promises = [];
    for (const b of bounds) {
      const q = this.db.collection('feeder'/*, ref => {
        return ref
          .orderBy("address")
          .startAt(b[0])
          .endAt(b[1])
      }*/)
      promises.push(q.get());
    }

    // Collect all the query results together into a single list
    Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
      var matchingDocs: Array<Array<string>> = [];
      var alreadyMatched: Array<string> = [];

      for (const snap of snapshots) {
        snap.subscribe(res => {
          res.forEach(data => {
            var point = this.feederService.getLatLng(data.id);
            point.subscribe(r => {
              const lat = r[0];
              const lng = r[1]
  
              // We have to filter out a few false positives due to GeoHash
              // accuracy, but most will match
              const distanceInKm = geofire.distanceBetween([lat, lng], center);
              const distanceInM = distanceInKm * 1000;
              if (distanceInM <= radiusInM) {
                if(!alreadyMatched.includes(data.id)) {
                  this.authService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
                    var uid = 'noUid'
                    if(this.authService.isAuth()) {
                      uid = user.uid;
                    }
                    this.feederService.getFeederById(data.id).subscribe(feeder => {
                      if(feeder.state) {
                        matchingDocs.push([data.id, uid]);
                      }
                    })
                  });
                  alreadyMatched.push(data.id);
                }
              }
            })
          })
        })
      }
      
      return matchingDocs;
    }).then((matchingDocs) => {
      // Process the matching documents
      this.matchingDocs = matchingDocs;
      console.log(this.matchingDocs)    // <------- HERE
    });
  }
```

My page after loading well `console.log()` what I want. So I want that my `.html` acts like it is an asynch request.
[/EDIT]
Does someone have any idea on how to fix this display problem ?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Hey Franck, to be honest, I wouldn’t know where to start. I’m afraid there is so much wrong with your code that a full refactor is probably wise. I can see looped observable subscriptions inside other subscriptions inside a Promise and all mutable data. All of which are really problematic. I would advice to learn a bit more about RxJs and operators. Sorry I can’t give you more.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your time! If you want to know, the major part of the .ts comes from [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries), for the observables and subscriptions, this is just the verification part. I imagine that there is a better way to do so... so if you have an online lesson to advise me, I will learn what I have to!

Comment: @deborahkurata has a very good RxJs course. You can find it here: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/rxjs-angular-reactive-development

Answer (score 0):

After `this.matchingDocs = matchingDocs;` line just put the below code should solve the issue:

```
this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
```

Try this out!

```
...
}).then((matchingDocs) => {
  // Process the matching documents
  this.matchingDocs = matchingDocs;
  this.changeDetection.detectChanges(); 
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank youy, but that didn't worked, anything changed...

Comment: can you please share the full working code on stackblitz so that issue can be diagnosed ?

Comment: I'm rewriting all the code, if the error stay, I will do that, thank you !